# SpringSecurity, security annotations and MVC validation

Tags: validation, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a RESTful application developed with SpringMVC 4. Normally I use the Security annotations on the service layer and it works well. Now I have the following (common) situation: the REST controller receives a JSON that needs to be validated, but as the security is on the service layer the validation is performed **before** the security control. This means that an unaothorized user receives all the validation errors **before** the access denied error.

I have tried to move the @Secured annotation on the controller method, but strangely it does not always work.

The ideal solution would be to move the validation in the service layer, but it does not seem possible.

What is the best solution in these cases?

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl {

   @Secured("IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY") 
   public ResponseDto serviceMethod(RequestDto richiesta) {
      //Do some stuff
   }

}



@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/blabla")
public class BlablaController {

    @Autowired
    MyService myService;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody MyResponseDto blablaMethod(@RequestBody @Valid RequestDto req) {
      return myService.serviceMethod(req);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to keep things separated. Usually you secure URI paths via HTTP security. If there is a business logic involved in the validation, implement the logic on service layer.

Comment: If I move the @Secured("IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY") annotation to the controller's method it is ignored. I did not understand but the security annotations applied to the controller's methods it does not always work. this is the main reason why I have moved all the security to the layer of business logic.

Comment: Spring's AOP works on interfaces (unless you use `aspectj`). This is why it can not work on controllers, unless you have interfaces for their methods - and that would be quite an overkill. You should use HTTP security for securing controllers - http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-httpsecurity.

Comment: @PavelHoral it will happily work on classes too if it's enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I answer to my own question.

The solution was to enable validation at the service layer and validate the bean when service method is invoked.

In my applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor"/>
```

And in MyService interface:

```
@Validated
public interface MyService {
    ResponseDto serviceMethod(@Valid RequestDto richiesta);
}
```

Hope this helps someone else.